# How to get total row count from .xlsx file using Apache POI event model API

Tags: java, apache-poi, saxparser

I am referring this document https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api to read large excel (.xlsx) file. I am able to read whole .xlsx file using this approach but stuck to get total row number while reading the record from file.

As per requirement, User is uploading .xlsx file and data are always available in first column (A) of excel. I reading the record one by one from .xlsx file and sending to queue. But I also want to send total count of records with every sending data to queue.

I almost spent 3 hours for this solution but did not find with suitable code.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Keep track of the row numbers as you parse the file, and return the max one seen?

Comment: @Gagravarr I did not get it. Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: Look at the `startElement` method in the code you linked to - that shows how you get the cell's reference, which includes row number. Just track the max value of that as you parse

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks for elaboration. I have already tracking row number for different purpose but I need total row number eveytime when 'endElement' method is called. As per requirement, I want to send total row number with every record to queue. Inside endElement method, I wrote this logic to send in queue.

Comment: You'll have to parse the file twice then, once to get the total then a second time with the values

Comment: @Gagravarr Yes got your point. Can you share code snippet for this solution?

Comment: @Gagravarr I got the total row number by parsing the file twice. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 2nd streaming sample in the POI examples. http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java

This one uses a different streaming interface that exposes startRow and endRow events with row numbers.

Another approach would be to use excel-streaming-reader - see sample(https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/pjfanning/poi/sample/StreamingRead.java) - this could be modified to record the last the 'getRowNum()' vale from the last row.

Comment: Thank for the approach. In both cases, I will get total row number while reading the last row. But in my case, I required the total row number While reading the first record from excel.

Comment: excel-streaming-reader ('another approach' above) has a getLastRowNum() on its Sheet implementation